# How to execute an ActionResult using devexpress ribbon button?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

In my view i have a devexpress ribbon with a ribbon, like this:

```
@Html.DevExpress().Ribbon(settings =>
{
settings.ShowFileTab = false;
settings.Name = "ribbon";
var tab = settings.Tabs.Add("Options");
var tasksGroup = tab.Groups.Add("Range");
tasksGroup.Items.Add(MVCxRibbonItemType.DateEditItem, s =>
{
    s.Name = "inicialDate";
    s.Text = "Data Inicial";
});
tasksGroup.Items.Add(MVCxRibbonItemType.DateEditItem, s =>
{
    s.Name = "finalDate";
    s.Text = " Data Final";
});
tasksGroup.Items.Add(MVCxRibbonItemType.ButtonItem, b =>
{
    b.Text = "Send";
    b.ItemStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed;        
});
}).GetHtml()
```

I cant figure out how to execute a post in some action passing both date as parameter.
Some controls in mvc devepress have a really disguting documentation.
Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [link](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q569579) the DevExpress support recommended to use Client Side events to post data to the server side. Look at an example below

```
@Html.DevExpress().Ribbon(s=>
{
s.Name = "ribbon";
......
s.ClientSideEvents.CommandExecuted = "function (s,e) { OnCommandExecuted(s,e); }";
.....
tasksGroup.Items.Add(MVCxRibbonItemType.ButtonItem, b =>
{
    b.Text = "Send";
    b.Name = "SendData";
    ......
});
}).GetHtml()

<script>
  function OnCommandExecuted(s,e) {
    if (e.item.name == "SendData"){
      $.post("/controller/action?inicialDate=" + s.GetItemValueByName("inicialDate") + "&finalDate" + s.GetItemValueByName("finalDate"), function (data) {
      }, function (err) {
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: i defined the name of the js function but in the console i get this error: > Uncaught ReferenceError: OnCommandExecuted is not defined.Do you know what it could be?

Comment: This error means, that the DevExpress try to use function before it is defined on the page. Try to replace code to   s.ClientSideEvents.CommandExecuted = "function (s,e) { OnCommandExecuted(s,e); }";

Comment: Thanks man, works perfectly. But why devex try to execute the function before it is declared? it doesnt make sense for me. it should be a bug imo.

Comment: The DevExpress starts to link functions in header this is why you get an error when you define you function definition in html body